# npm deleting failed install module

Tags: node.js, npm, node-canvas

I am attempting to `npm install canvas-superjoe` (a fork of canvas) on Windows, but I am running into a link problem:

`LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\GTK\lib\libpng.lib' [c:\...\node_modules\canvas-superjoe\build\canvas.
vcxproj]`

I am trying to debug this link error.  I know that the file `libpng.lib` does not exist, and that the directory structure looks like this:

`C:\GTK\
        bin\
            libpng15-15.dll
        lib\
            libpng.dll.a
            libpng15.dll.a`

However, I cannot access the canvas.vcxproj file, as npm seems to be deleting the `canvas-superjoe` directory after the npm install fails.

Is there some way I can just *download* the `canvas-superjoe` module, so that I can manually try to install and/or debug the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try running `npm install` with `--force`. This worked for me.